# How to merge several format multi-dimensional array into one array, and make calucalation using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, when I `json_decode()` it, I got below array:

```
Array
(
    [avg] => 1.1
    [day] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
        )

    [channels] => Array
        (
            [ali] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 5
                    [rate] => 6
                )
        )
)

Array
(
    [avg] => 3.3
    [day] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 8
        )

    [channels] => Array
        (
            [ali] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 5
                    [rate] => 8
                )
        )
)
```

How can I merge these arrays into one, meanwhile, I want all the values to be calculated as average, such as `(1.1+3.3)/2 = 2.2`. We have to loop the `channels` sub array, because it's dynamic, ie. not only `ali` but also several channels as well may appear.

So the supposed result should be: (All the structure of the sub arrays are same)

```
Array
(
    [avg] => 2.2
    [day] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [channels] => Array
        (
            [ali] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 5
                    [rate] => 7
                )
        )
)
```

What I tried is very complicated. First, I pop the first array in the arrays, and loop the left array to sum all of the values of them. Once done, I loop the array again to calculate the average value, but it costs about 30 lines of code. I don't think it's a very good way to do this. Is there a more suitable way to do this?

Comment: Go ahead and post those 30 lines. If it already works, it'll make what you're trying trying to do abundantly clear.